# Error handling in Password reset flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am building a Flutter/Firebase app with reset password functionality.

For modularity, I keep my auth functions in an AuthService Class.

```
class AuthService{
 final auth.FirebaseAuth _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
 // **8** FUNCTION TO RESET PASSWORD
 Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
   try {
   return await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
    } catch (e) {
   print(e.toString());
  }
 }
//  **8**

}
```

Then I call it in my widget like this:

```
final auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
...
await auth.resetPassword(email);
```

When I add a .then method to go to a route when successful, it redirects to the new route even when there is an error.  I have tried to add a .catch method but that throws an exception.

How can I go about this?

```
       await auth.resetPassword(email).then((value) =>
            Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
               const AndroidRecoverySuccess())));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Return bool value after `sendPasswordResetEmail`, also your Future should return bool. Here is the working code:

```
 Future<bool> resetPassword(String email) async {
   try {
      await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);

      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
   }
 }
```

(optional) You can use `FirebaseAuthException` for better UX:

```
  Future<bool> resetPassword(String email) async {
    try {
      await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);

      return true;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {    
      if (e.code.toString() == 'invalid-email') {
        // setState(() {message 'Invalid email address.';});
      }

      if (e.code.toString() == 'missing-email') {
        //...
      }

      if (e.code.toString() == 'user-not-found') {
        //...
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I then call this function and use the error message in the widget?

Comment: Use text widget or modal w/e you want, show error message ```setState(() {message 'Invalid email address.';});```

Comment: I am trying to trigger this method after an "onPressed", which means I cannot assign a boolean value to that. Is there a workaround?